# Can I connect 2 external monitors to my 12" Retina MacBook (early-2015)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Can I connect two external monitors to my 12" Retina MacBook (early-2015)

How do I do it and can it be VGA or only HDMI

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question as it's not a duplicate. The questions are about two different computers and the answers are different. The other question is about a 15" MacBook Pro with a nVidia GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB graphics card installed. This question is about a 12" Retina MacBook (early-2015) with only Intel HD Graphics 5300 on board. The answer in the other question is wrong for this computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This MacBook can simultaneously support the **internal display** as well as up to 3840x2160 at 30 Hz or up to 4096x2160 at 24Hz on **one external display**.

In other words, connecting two external Thunderbolt Displays is **not officially supported by Apple**. The two displays are the internal display and an external display.

If you're still interested in connecting one external display, since this MacBook has a single USB-C port and no *traditional* video port, you'll need an adapter to connect the display. Apple provides support for both HDMI and VGA via the following respective adapters:

- the [Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) for HDMI monitors, and also allows you to connect a standard USB device and a USB-C charging cable.
- the [Apple USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1L2AM/A/usb-c-vga-multiport-adapter) for VGA monitors. Like the HDMI adapter, this also allows you to connect a standard USB device and a USB-C charging cable.

Once you have the appropriate adapter, it's just a case of connecting the cable between it and your monitor.

Of course, you may choose to purchase 3rd party adapters instead of the Apple branded ones.

Comment: I didn't know he was talking about the 12" Macbook, otherwise I wouldn't have answered....? Can just comment to tell me, no need to downvote.

Comment: That's shame but thanks for answering. I do have an Apple VGA to USBC adapter which I use for 1 external monitor

Comment: @emotality Actually I wasn't the one who downvoted you. I rarely downvote something and when I do I always explain why.